# Why am I getting a list undefined data no my drop down list?

Tags: jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

I have two `select` elements on my html, the first `select` should be populated with data from the database and the second should be populated with data depending on the selected item of the first `select`. However I managed to get value on the first and i am having problems with the second `select`, it is returning undefined, with an accurate expected count of items but not displaying the name of the item, just displays a list of undefined. Please Help... Here is the Code:

**1. Html**

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        Category:
        <select asp-for="CategoryID" id="CategoryDD" class="form-control" asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.ListOfCategories,"CategoryID","CategoryName"))">
            <option value="">--Select Category--</option>
        </select>
    </div>

</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        Item Name:
        <select asp-for="Id" id="ItemDD" class="form-control" asp-items="@(new SelectList("","Id","ItemName"))">
            <option value="">--Select Item--</option>
        </select>

    </div>
</div>
```

**2. Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#CategoryDD").change(function () {
    console.log("Feching Items");
    $("#ItemDD").empty();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@Url.Action("GetItems")",
        dataType: "Json",               
        data: { id: $("#CategoryDD").val() },
        success: function (items) {
            console.log("Success!!!");
            $.each(items, function (i, item) {
                $("#ItemDD").append("<option value='"+item.Id+"'>"+ item.ItemName + "</option>");
            });
        },
        error: function (ex) {
            alert('Error Loading Items ' + ex);
        }
    });
    return false;
})
```

});

**3. MVC Controller**

```
    public JsonResult GetItems(int id)
    {
       var objSelectListItem = (from obj in _context.OrderItem.Where(cat => cat.CategoryID == id)

                             select new SelectListItem()
                             {
                                 Text = obj.ItemName,
                                 Value = obj.Id.ToString(),                                 
                             }).ToList();

        return Json(objSelectListItem);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code works as expected now, i can't believe this simple line of code just got me worked up for 24 hours. Here is my solution code:

I changed this line:

```
$("#ItemDD").append("<option value='"+item.Id+"'>"+ item.ItemName + "</option>");
```

To this:

```
 $.each(result, function (i, item) {
 $("#ItemDD").append($("<option></option>").val(item.value).html(item.text));
```

});

Comment: Thank you for your post. This solves my problem too.