# Cascade Dropdownlist by JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core

I am creating an asp.net core cascade dropdownlist with JQuery. The first dropdownlist- Areas binds to Viewbag.areas. The second dropdownlist-Degrees is populating based on the first dropdownlist selected value. The JsonResult GetDegree() method returns a list of data. For some reasons, my second dropdownlist options displays as a list of undefined data when using JQuery. Do I need to bind asp-items to the second dropdownlist and how to do it?  Thanks in advance!

```
controller:
    [BindProperty]
    public int AreaId { get; set; }
    [BindProperty]
    public int? DegreeId { get; set; }
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
                ViewBag.Areas = GetAreas();
                var qry = (from a in _context.Degrees
                           where a.AreaId == AreaId  && a.Active == true
                           select a).ToList();
                return View(qry);
    }
    public JsonResult GetDegree()
        {
            List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();
         
            var degrees = (from a in _context.Degrees
                           where a.AreaId==AreaId
                           select new SelectListItem
                           {
                               Value = a.DegreeId.ToString(),
                               Text = a.DegreeName,
                               Selected = (a.DegreeId== 0)
                           });
            

            if (degrees != null)
            {
                //assign 0 to the first option
                list.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Select a Degree", Value = "0" });
                foreach (var item in degrees)
                {
                    list.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = item.Text, Value = item.Value });
                }
                return Json(new SelectList(list, "Value", "Text"));
            }
            else
            {
                return Json(new SelectList(list, "0", "Select a Degree"));
            }

        }

View:

    <form asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Home">
    <label for="AreaId">Areas</label>
    <select id="AreaId" name="AreaId" asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.Areas,"Value","Text"))">
        <option value="">--Select --</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <label for="DegreeId">Degrees</label>
    <select id="DegreeId" name="DegreeId" value=""/>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" /><br />
</form>
@section scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#AreaId").change(function () {
        $("#DegreeId").empty();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '@Url.Action("GetDegree")',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { AreaId: $("#AreaId").val() },            
                success: function (degrees) {
                    $.each(degrees, function (i, degree) {
                            $("#DegreeId").append('<option value="' + degree.Value  +'">'+
                                degree.Text + '</option>');
                    });
                },
                error: function (ex) {
                    console.log(ex);
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Find the solution from this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59600959/why-am-i-getting-a-list-undefined-data-no-my-drop-down-list . change the code  $("#DegreeId").append($("<option></option>").val(degree.value).html(degree.text));

Answer (score 0):

Find the solution from this post stackoverflow.com/questions/59600959/… . change the code $("#DegreeId").append($("").val(degree.value).html(degree.text));